# warning: implicit declaration of function 'Min' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c99

I'm getting the error

*warning: implicit declaration of function 'Min' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]*

When trying to find the minimum value from 3 inputs without touching the main.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void minVal (double x, double y, double z, double minVal)
{
    if (x<y && x<z)
        minVal = x;

    else if (y<x && y<z)
        minVal = y;

    else if (z<x && z<y)
        minVal = z;
}

int main(void) {
    double x, y, z, minVal;

    printf("Please enter three numeric values: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &x, &y, &z);
    minVal = Min(x, y, z);
    printf("Min(%0.10f, %0.10f, %0.10f) = %0.10f\n", x, y, z, minVal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `Min`? Perhaps it's time for you to find some proper book or tutorial (or go back to your class-notes or teacher) to figure out what the problem is (and there are more than one!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your teacher calls up a student who is absent in the class, all students may yell "He isn't here!"

Lets look at the warning:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'Min' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

This means, that you are trying to use `Min` without declaring it in your code, and that isn't allowed.
It not an error, but a warning, which will cause a linker error eventually.

Here:

```
minVal = Min(x, y, z);
```

So, either you need to write a function called `Min`, or you need to replace `Min` with some function that you have already declared. For example,

```
void minVal (double x, double y, double z, double minVal)
```

Now, even if you change the call from `Min` to `minVal`, it won't work. Because your code has a function called `minVal` and a variable with the same name. Thats chaotic. Make a habit to refrain declaring variables and function with a same name.

This function is returning `void`, and you are trying to determine the minimum of 3 inputs with `double` as data type, and assign the value to last variable passed as an argument. Doable, but not convenient as compared to returning a value, right?

> When trying to find the minimum value from 3 inputs without touching the main.

I'd suggest this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double Min(double x, double y, double z)
{
    if (x<y && x<z)
        return x;
    else if (y<x && y<z)
        return y;
    else if (z<x && z<y)
        return z;
    else
        return 0.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    double x, y, z, minVal = 0.0;

    printf("Please enter three numeric values: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &x, &y, &z);
    minVal = Min(x, y, z);
    printf("Min(%0.10f, %0.10f, %0.10f) = %0.10f\n", x, y, z, minVal);

    return 0;
}
```

This code has following changes from what you had come up with:

- Function renamed to `Min` from `minVal`. Note that usually it is preferred to use verbs/actions for function name, so that its easy to interpret what the function does. So, if I have the liberty to change `main()` function, I'll use the name `Get_minValue` instead of `Min` in all the places (declaration and the function call).
- Change the return type of `Min` to `double`, so that I can return the value rather than assigning it to an argument.

You can still make it better by getting rid of the `minVal` variable, I'll let you figure that out :-)

Additionally, C99 is old, next time you compile your code, make sure you compile it with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) you can find more information on compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, it is a warning, not an error.

You're seeing this message because you're calling a function `Min`, which is not declared anywhere. While compilation will succeed (with a warning), linking will probably fail because `Min` isn't defined either.

The function you're probably trying to call is named `minVal` in your code, not `Min`.

However, you can't call `minVal` from your `main` as it is now because you've also defined a local variable called `minVal`, which shadows the function name. To fix this, you'd have to rename this variable:

```
double min;
...
min = minVal(x, y, z);
```

Alternatively, rename the function:

```
void Min(double x, double y, double z, double minVal)
...
```

This will cause further errors:

- Your `minVal` function does not return a value (its return type is `void`).
- Your `minVal` function takes 4 arguments, not 3 (but it ignores the 4th one).

The last point deserves further attention. In C function arguments are passed by value, so

```
f(x);
```

cannot modify `x`. Similarly, in `minVal` the last parameter (confusingly also called `minVal`) is just a local copy of the argument, so assigning to it has no effect ouside of the function.

You should remove the `minVal` parameter and `return` a value instead.

Comment: Warning or error doesn't make the matter more or less severe. It is a diagnostic message pointing out a C language violation, and as such pretty severe. If you wish the compiler to give an error when you write invalid C code, you must compile with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: the C language doesn't allow you to call functions (or macros) that are not defined. This was changed in the C language in the year 1999, which is why it says "C99".

In order to fix the problem, you must provide a function `Min`. And that's that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already properly answered, would like to add a comment on the use of a void-function.

```
void minVal (double x, double y, double z, double minVal)
```

minVal is most-likely meant to return the smallest value. In this simple function with only one return-value best choice is indeed to change your code to:

```
double minVal (double x, double y, double z, double minVal)
```

But what if you have to return more as one value, or you have to return a status (for example two or three equal numbers are entered) and a value? Then you need to rely on call-by-reference. In C pointers are the way to go.

```
void minVal (double x, double y, double z, double* min)
{
    if (x<y && x<z)
        *min = x;

    else if (y<x && y<z)
        *min = y;

    else if (z<x && z<y)
        *min = z;
}

int main(void) {
    double x, y, z, minValue;

    printf("Please enter three numeric values: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &x, &y, &z);
    minVal(x, y, z, &minValue);
    printf("Min(%0.10f, %0.10f, %0.10f) = %0.10f\n", x, y, z, minValue);

return 0;
}
```

In this case, with &minValue you pass the address of minValue instead of the value of minValue into the minVal function. In the minVal function *min means store the value to the address pointed by double* min.